# Azure Media Services - Programmatically Transcode Blob into Asset

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

I am able to programmatically upload a local mp4 file into blob storage that is associated with my Azure Media Services.

How can I programmatically transcode the blob into an asset?  preferably C#

I have a working ps1 script that I need to convert to a C# application.  Following along with the script, my next step is to programmatically create a transcoding job to create the asset.  I've been going down too many rabbit holes, just need to find a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic! Have you tried out one of our many samples that show how to do that already?

Each of the samples in our .NET repo here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/VideoEncoding
show how to upload and encode an asset into a new Output asset using a Transform and a Job entity.  After that the sample just downloads the contents of the output asset back to your local system.

Hopefully it was not too difficult to locate our samples from our documentation. Otherwise, I might have some work for our doc team to make it easier to find for you. Watch out for Google searches that lead you to the older deprecated v2 API.  Most of the time it is mentioned on the page if it is deprecated. Don't ask ChatGPT - as it is very wrong... using 2019 information about v2 API.

Comment: I wasn't sure which example to use, but I got through it.  There was some other difficulties, the `common_util` project wasn't obvious.  I got my stuff mostly working, but my token expires after about 1.5 hrs and I get exception `ExpiredAuthenticationToken`.  Where can I adjust that timeout ?

Comment: Yes, we are trying to re-structure our .NET samples now in that repo in the "track2" branch  - which uses a newer version of the SDK from the Azure .NET SDK team.  We are just in the process of updating those. Working to remove te common utils and keep the samples as standalone as possible to avoid confusion.  

On the token issue, you might be referring to how the AAD authentication token works.  AAD sets that to expire  randomly between 60-90 minutes.

Comment: See here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-policy-properties-in-depth